# Code Signing Error Certificate identity  

Tags: ios, xcode4, code-signing, certificate, xcode4.4

```
Certificate identity 'iPhone Developer:myname etc..' appears more than once in the keychain. The codesign tool requires there only be one
```

i was just about to send my app off to itunes connect and i deleted the certificates from my keychain and i have downloaded them again and as i run my device i get the above ^^

heres some images of my project and keychain now?

[image]

[image]

what do i need to do thanks in advance

edited still getting no where

[image]

still cant solve it please help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on your project in project navigator 
On the rich side window look for code signing and choose the recommended one.
If you are developing on device use the development profile
if it is for app store submission use Distribution profile
[image]

Comment: I can still see some "dont code sign" in debug and release change them to recommended provisioning profiles. Basically try changing all of them to recommended provisioning profile.

Comment: im still not sure whats wrong i have done the same as above and still have a problem do you known any-think i can try ??

Answer (score 0):

Perform the steps from the Apple [tech note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG3).